# Custom Okta registration UI

Tags: ios, okta

I'm integrating Okta into an iOS app and I need to create a custom new user registration UI. I can't seem to find anything on this in the documentation but this must be a common use case.

Is there an SDK available to help with this (similar to login) or will I have to hit the APIs manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hitting [this endpoint](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#create-user-with-password) manually is the solution. Just make sure you're providing an API token, not a user token.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a backend application to make a call to Okta to create user if you need a custom registration UI as it requires an API token or access token with high privilege.

You can use one of the management SDK's based on your backend application language.

You can find some links below: 
.Net SDK: https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-dotnet 
Java SDK: https://github.com/okta/okta-sdk-java

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you saying I can't register a user directly with Okta from the iOS app, but have to build some sort of intermediate API with high privileges? I've been trying to hit [this endpoint](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#create-user-with-password) manually when the user registers but given the token it needs to complete the request it seems like this may not be the answer I'm looking for.